# How to copy text and styles Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to copy text to clipboard with styles but it copies the html code instead of the appearance

```
<button cdkCopyToClipboard="You copied me!<b>hello</b>">Click to copy</button>
```

I am using this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clipboard-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The result that i have when i paste in any site:
"You copied me! `<b>` hello `</b>`"

Expected result:
You copied me! **hello**

Answer (score 0):

Copy functionality is working for me. For testing I clicked on Copy button and pasted in Using a Function field. It worked for me.
Please  elaborate in more details about the issue.